# How to calculate t-values from percent ranks?

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

A table from a psychological test is giving percent ranks (PR).

How can I transform those into t-values **by calculation**? 
(Assuming normal distribution.)

I found a lot of references on how to transform z --> t, but none on PR --> t.

Way back in university, we had tables with the bell-curve, to look up PR, z-values, t-values and stanines - but how to **calculate**?

Comment: check this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test

Comment: When you say $t$-values, it suggests that you're using one Gosset's $t$-distributions (not the normal distribution, which always uses $z$-values).  You need the $\textit{inverse}$ of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the particular distribution.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: I think this is different from what I need.

Comment: @SammyBlack: I am not very experienced in statistics, but I am quite sure that those psychological tests at least assume normal distribution. You're right, z-values are common, but t-values, too. I found a lot of references on how to transform z --> t, but none on PR --> t. Way back in university, we had tables with the bell-curve, PR, z-values, t-values and stanines - but how to calculate?

Comment: try http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @johnmangual: Thanks, didn't know about it!

Comment: @michi I suggest you to learn the meaning of the things that you are doing. Tables will not help you. Mostly you will forget them. What remains will be the ideas, if you could grapped one of course. For example what does $t$ mean? when you ask this questions you will immediately go to the wiki page that I posted. After you learn what is going on, then you can build the relation with your PR values etc.. This is just a suggestion..

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I can really relate to what you are suggesting. As my time is limited, I chose to explore areas different from PR-->t - but will have to follow your suggestion if not someone will post a formula ;-)